# Change permission for directories recursively from drwxr-xr-x to drwxrwsrwx (setting setgid for the group users)

Tags: python, linux, permissions, operating-system, file-permissions

I am looking out for a way in python for adding special permissions for the folders recursively in python, I can find them mostly on linux commands but not with python.

I need to change permission for the groups users to setguid for directories recursively .

Comment: What's the use of setgid if your directories are writable to all? Did you mean `drwxrwsr-x`? If so, chmod the directories to `0o2775` (or `0o2777`, if you really meant `rwx` for user). You cannot do it recursively in Python in one command. If you are asking how to recursively enumerate directories in Python, please ask that — keep it one question per question, or it is likely to be closed for "lack of focus".

Comment: Split the problem into two: traverse directories recursively and change directory mode. Latter can be done with `os.chmod("foo", os.stat("foo").st_mode | stat.S_ISGID);`

Comment: On trying the above command, getting the stat NameError. Please check it

Comment: @BossBoss Did you `import stat`?

Comment: I think I missed it, it worked !!!. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with python-3.10.9:

```py
import os;
import stat;

for dirname in ([x[0] for x in os.walk("root")]):
    os.chmod(dirname, os.stat(dirname).st_mode | stat.S_ISGID);
```

Substitute `"root"` with name of directory to start from.

I'm not experiensed with python, so maybe it is possible to simplify the code.

Comment: Is there any proper os module documentation available for this. It worked , but if there is any reference can you share it here please.

Comment: It worked for 3.9.9 for me.

Comment: @BossBoss I found it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html and here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html